node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 throw err
Node v18.18.2
ts-node v10.9.2 (@latest)
When typing: ts-node (-v)
I'm getting the following error.
Error: Cannot find module 'arg'
Require stack:
    - /usr/share/nodejs/ts-node/dist/bin.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/ts-node/dist/bin.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
    (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [ '/usr/share/nodejs/ts-node/dist/bin.js' ]
    }
    #Node.js v18.18.2

On
Windows WSL2
#NVM: used to install and manage (use) NPM versions.
In my path:
"$HOME/.nvm/node/node_modules/.bin/ts-node"
"$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node"

How did you install ts-node ?

In my $HOME dir: npm i ts-node.

\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\tomcatzy.nvm\node_modules.bin                          \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\usr\bin                                                                                    Both of these dir have node and ts-node in them.                                                                .profile and .bashrc have $PATH's for both: Tried to both of the paths without succes.
